# JFrame cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, swing

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class shapes extends JPanel{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new Jframe("Test"); // Error here on JFrame
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(400,200);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(Jframe.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // error here on Frame
      draw object = new draw();
    frame.add(object);


    object.drawing();



  }
}
```

Simple  2 errors keep appearing that are unknown to the system.
It appears that JFrame is not being imported correctly. No searches so far have come with a solution.

Comment: Jframe should be JFrame. Uppercase F

Comment: Remember: Java is case sensitive!

Answer (score 7):

`Jframe` should be `JFrame`.   Uppercase F